# Open source statistics library for C# for generating random number of various distributions?

Tags: c#, statistics, simulation, probability

This is for simulation.  In particular, I'm trying to generate natural sounding words and names, and the uniform distribution in the Random class provides doesn't cut it.

This isn't a dupe question because the similar questions weren't look for C# random number generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an article and some code from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Random.aspx).

Comment: +1 great article. There are a couple of other unanswered SO questions about generating distributions floating around - this is a great resource for those, too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the package [Iridium](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com) of Math.Net, an open source Math library.

One of the Iridium features is:

- non-uniform random generators (normal, poisson, binomial, ...)